# How to convert svg styling from Internal CSS to Presentation Attributes?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a plugin for adove XD. I am exporting text as svg. By default adove xd api exports svg as "internal CSS" style. But from adove XD you can export svg as "internal CSS" or "Presentation Attribute" styling. Is there any way that I can convert "internal CSS" styled svg to "Presentation Attribute"?